# How to Check the existance of a directory on Remote server while FTP frm UNIX to Windows

Tags: windows, unix, ftp

I am attempting to FTP files from UNIX server to Windows Server; in the current senario,

if my destination directory is not present then it FTP's the file to default directory.

My fix for the situation was to check if the directory exist and only then FTP the files. Only I do not know how to implement the same. PFA and advice.

```
srcpath=/home/fcadmin/Repository_ftp_test/venx

CS=/FCreportsrepository/Host
SCR_PATH=/home/fcadmin/Repository_ftp_test/venx
dpcpath=/fchostrjs/fcprdapp/dpcreports
logpath=/fchostrjs/fcprdapp/dpclog


for j in `cat venx.txt`
do

ftp -i -n <<EOF>ftp_me.log
open 10.226.14.102
user ftpuser abc!123
binary on
prompt
cd $CS
lcd $srcpath 
if[<Directory Exists>];
then echo "Directory exists";
mput $j;
else
echo "Specified Directory doesnt Exist">>ftp_me.log;
exit;
fi
EOF

EXITFTP=$?
if test $EXITFTP -ne 0; 
then echo "$D ERROR FTP" >> $LOG;
exit ;
fi

if (grep "^Not connected." ftp_me.log); then echo "$D ERROR FTP CONNECT" >> $LOG; fi 
if (grep "No such file" ftp_me.log); then echo "$D ERROR FTP NO SUCH FILE" >> $LOG; fi 
if (grep "access denied" ftp_me.log); then echo "$D ERROR FTP ACCESS DENIED" >> $LOG; fi
if (grep "^Please login" ftp_me.log); then echo "$D ERROR FTP LOGIN" >> $LOG; fi

done
```